# Acts 13:19-20: Accuracy of Greek Text and Reference of "the four-hundred and fifty" in Codex Sinaiticus

Tags: acts, textual-criticism, chronology

The Received Text on Acts 13:19-20 differs from such MSS as the Codex Sinaiticus (א), Alexandrinus (A), and the Codex Vaticanus (B).

Questions:

1. Is it possible that the Received Text is accurate?
2. In the verses discussing periods of time (v. 19-21), does the variance in Greek case make any difference?
3. In the Codex Sinaiticus, etc., to what does "the four-hundred and fifty" refer?

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange, thanks for contributing - this is an excellent first question! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423)

Comment: Regarding your first question, how would you define "accurate"?

Comment: You mean Acts 13, not Acts 3

Answer (score 1):

The differences between the Textus Receptus and the other witnesses are really trivial (see below).  The major difference is a simple reversal in word order. In verse 20, the Textus Receptus reads:

> (a) και μετα ταυτα (b) ως ετεσιν τετρακοσιοις και πεντηκοντα
>
> Lit. (a) "and after these things" (b) "about years four hundred and fifty ..."

Whereas the Codices read:

> (b) ως ετεσιν τετρακοσιοις και πεντηκοντα (a) και μετα ταυτα
>
> Lit. (b) "about years four hundred and fifty" (a) "and after these things"

The issue of the four-hundred fifty years relates not to the manuscripts - they are all consistent - but rather to punctuation, which was not in any ancient manuscript (as neither were verse numbers).

In the second edition of *A Textual Commentary on the Greek New Testament*, Bruce Metzger writes (p.358-59):

> The problems of verses 19 and 20 are both textual and exegetical. The
> Textus Receptus (following Db E P Ψ and most minuscules) speaks of the
> period of the judges following the division of Canaan: “and after that
> he gave unto them judges about the space of four hundred and fifty
> years, until Samuel the prophet” (AV). On the other hand the
> Alexandrian text transfers the temporal clause to the end of ver. 19,
> and thus makes the four hundred fifty years cover a period prior to
> the institution of the judges: “… when he had destroyed seven nations
> in the land of Canaan, he gave them their land as an inheritance, for
> about four hundred and fifty years. (20) And after that he gave them
> judges until Samuel the prophet” (RSV).
>
> The chronological reckoning involved in the reading of the Textus
> Receptus agrees almost exactly with that of Josephus (443 years,
> according to Antiquities, viii.iii.1), and both differ widely from 1
> Kgs 6:1, where it is said that Solomon (who lived long after the
> judges) began his temple in the four hundred and eightieth (so the
> Hebrew text; but the Septuagint text reads four hundred and fortieth)
> year after the Exodus. The reckoning that lies behind the Alexandrian
> text evidently covers the four hundred years of the stay in Egypt
> (ver. 17) plus the forty years in the wilderness (ver. 18), plus about
> ten years for the distribution of the land (Jos 14).
>
> On the surface, however, the Alexandrian text appears to limit the
> four hundred fifty years to the time that passed between the division
> of the land by Joshua and the institution of the judges. It was
> probably in order to prevent the reader from drawing such an erroneous
> conclusion that scribes transposed the temporal clause to the
> following sentence, producing the reading of the Textus Receptus.
>
> It may be added that when modern translators of the Alexandrian text
> break up the one Greek sentence of verses 17, 18, and 19 into several
> different sentences, it is almost inevitable that the reader will take
> the temporal clause of ver. 19 as referring only to the final
> sentence.

#### 1550 Stephen's Textus Receptus

> και καθελων εθνη επτα εν γη χανααν **κατεκληροδοτησεν αυτοις** την
> γην αυτων
>
> **και μετα ταυτα ως ετεσιν τετρακοσιοις και πεντηκοντα** εδωκεν κριτας εως σαμουηλ του προφητου
>
> κακειθεν ητησαντο βασιλεα και εδωκεν αυτοις ο θεος τον σαουλ υιον κις
> ανδρα εκ φυλης βενιαμιν ετη τεσσαρακοντα

I have boldfaced words that vary between manuscripts

#### Codex Siniaticus

> και καθελων εθνη επτα εν γη χανααν **κατεκληροδοτησεν** την γην
> αυτων
>
> **ως ετεσιν τετρακοσιοις και πεντηκοντα και μετα τουτα** εδωκεν
> κριτας εως σαμουηλ του προφητου
>
> κακειθεν ητησαντο βασιλεα και εδωκεν αυτοις ο θεος τον σαουλ υιον
> κις ανδρα εκ φυλης βενιαμιν ετη τεσσαρακοντα

#### Codex Alexandrinus

> και καθελων εθνη επτα εν γη χανααν **κατεκληροδοτησεν αυτοις** την
> γην αυτων
>
> **ως ετεσιν τετρακοσιοις και πεντηκοντα και μετα τουτα** εδωκεν
> κριτας εως σαμουηλ του προφητου
>
> κακειθεν ητησαντο βασιλεα και εδωκεν αυτοις ο θεος τον σαουλ υιον
> κις ανδρα εκ φυλης βενιαμιν ετη τεσσαρακοντα

#### Codex Vaticanus

> και καθελων εθνη επτα εν γη χανααν **κατεκληροδοτησεν αυτοις** την
> γην αυτων
>
> **ως ετεσιν τετρακοσιοις και πεντηκοντα και μετα τουτα** εδωκεν
> κριτας εως σαμουηλ του προφητου
>
> κακειθεν ητησαντο βασιλεα και εδωκεν αυτοις ο θεος τον σαουλ υιον
> κις ανδρα εκ φυλης βενιαμιν ετη τεσσαρακοντα